# Errno 111 Connection refused when using Celery with SQS

Tags: django, celery, amazon-sqs

I am having a problem when I run the `celery status` or `celery purge` commands.

```
 File "/usr/bin/celery", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/__main__.py", line 30, in main
    main()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 81, in main
    cmd.execute_from_commandline(argv)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 769, in execute_from_commandline
    super(CeleryCommand, self).execute_from_commandline(argv)))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 306, in execute_from_commandline
    return self.handle_argv(self.prog_name, argv[1:])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 761, in handle_argv
    return self.execute(command, argv)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 693, in execute
    ).run_from_argv(self.prog_name, argv[1:], command=argv[0])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 310, in run_from_argv
    sys.argv if argv is None else argv, command)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 372, in handle_argv
    return self(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 269, in __call__
    ret = self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 472, in run
    replies = I.run('ping', **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 324, in run
    return self.do_call_method(args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 346, in do_call_method
    callback=self.say_remote_command_reply)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 385, in call
    return getattr(i, method)(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/control.py", line 99, in ping
    return self._request('ping')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/control.py", line 70, in _request
    timeout=self.timeout, reply=True,
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/control.py", line 306, in broadcast
    limit, callback, channel=channel,
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/pidbox.py", line 283, in _broadcast
    chan = channel or self.connection.default_channel
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 755, in default_channel
    self.connection
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 740, in connection
    self._connection = self._establish_connection()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 695, in _establish_connection
    conn = self.transport.establish_connection()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/transport/pyamqp.py", line 112, in establish_connection
    conn = self.Connection(**opts)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/amqp/connection.py", line 165, in __init__
    self.transport = create_transport(host, connect_timeout, ssl)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/amqp/transport.py", line 294, in create_transport
    return TCPTransport(host, connect_timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/amqp/transport.py", line 95, in __init__
    raise socket.error(last_err)
socket.error: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

I am using SQS BROKER_URL.
The tasks are running fine, but when I want to purge the tasks on a queue (`celery purge -f`), I get the above error.

```
software -> celery:3.1.11 (Cipater) kombu:3.0.18 py:2.7.5
            billiard:3.3.0.17 py-amqp:1.4.5
platform -> system:Linux arch:64bit, ELF imp:CPython
loader   -> celery.loaders.default.Loader
settings -> transport:amqp results:disabled
```

My server has ports 22, 80, 443, 8000 ports open and there are tons of messages in the SQS `celery` queue, so the connection between celery and SQS should be fine.

Answer (score 11):

Based on [documentation of the commands status and purge](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/monitoring.html#commands) you need to provide celery with the celery app you're referring to so that it knows what broker to use.  By just typing `$celery purge` or by typing `$celery status` celery doesn't know what celery app you're targeting and so fails.

Therefore, go to your celery app

`$cd /path/to/your/celery/app/directory`

and then call celery purge on your app. In this example my directory has `celeryapp.py` and the contents are:

```
from config import config
from celery import Celery
celery_app = Celery('tasks', 
                    backend=config.celery_backend_uri, 
                    broker=config.celery_broker_uri)
celery_app.conf.update(
    CELERY_IMPORTS=(
        'app.module_a.tasks',   # we're not including our tasks here as
        'app.module_b.tasks',   # our tasks are in other files listed here
    )
)
```

the contents are not as important as our call, but they are provided to show that we have our celery app inside `celeryapp.py` so I can call

```
$celery -A celeryapp status
worker-name-a@node-name: OK
worker-name-b@node-name: OK
```

or

```
$celery -A celeryapp purge
WARNING: This will remove all tasks from queue: celery.
         There is no undo for this operation! 
(to skip this prompt use the -f option)
Are you sure you want to delete all tasks (yes/NO)? yes
No messages purged from 1 queue
```

I had a similar [question here](https://github.com/ask/flask-celery/issues/19#issuecomment-57621001) and Sol seemed to confirm that celery will output this error if no app is provided by stating

> How would it know what broker transport to use if you don't give it the location of the app?